# TableviewCell select and Move to another view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, mbcalendarkit

I used a MBCalendarKit.  This is an event shown on tableView method `- (void)calendarView:(CKCalendarView *)CalendarView didSelectEvent:(CKCalendarEvent *)event`. This method works same as `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`. I want to call the method `didSelectEvent` on tableView cell click event. How to move to another view controller on cell click ?and pass cell array data. How is it possible? Please help. Thank You

## Method

```
- (void)calendarView:(CKCalendarView *)CalendarView didSelectEvent:(CKCalendarEvent *)event
{
 //  A row is selected in the events table. (Use to push a detail view or whatever.)
 CalendarViewController*destVC = [[CalendarViewController alloc] init];
destVC.pure=arr;
[self presentViewController:destVC animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In tableview `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` Method :-

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

call your function :-

```
[self didSelectEvent:..
```

Also to move to another view controller use segue as follows in same didSelectRowAtIndexPath Method of tableView:-

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueName" sender:self];
```

Finally, to pass cell array use prepareForSegue:-

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueName"])
    {

        DestViewController *dest = segue.destinationViewController;
        dest.passedArr = Arr;

    }
}
```

**Note:-** "segueName" needs to be defined in Storyboard

Answer (score 0):

If you’re implementing `CKCalendarViewDelegate`, or subclassing `CKCalenderViewController`, from inside `calendarView:didSelectEvent:`, you can push a new view controller onto the navigation stack, or present it yourself, with `presentViewController:animated:completion:`.

If you want to pass the event through to the second view controller, assign it as a property before presenting or pushing the view controller.

<sub>Disclosure: I’m the author of MBCalendarKit.</sub>